# Optmize DISTINCT / LIMIT MySQL query for pagination

Tags: mysql, optimization, pagination, group-by, limit

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT group_id FROM products WHERE category = 12345 GROUP BY group_id LIMIT 0, 10
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM products WHERE category = 12345 LIMIT 0, 10
```

The LIMIT is used for pagination. I want to know how can I avoid MySQL to lookup all rows until it finds the 10 distinct group_ids that I want. For example if I did:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM products WHERE category = 12345 LIMIT 200, 10
```

It will scan the first 200 rows with category = 12345, than start collecting then 10 distinct group_ids?

**UPDATE:** What if I created an index on (group_id, category) ?

Comment: Is there an index on group_id? This would certainly speed up the lookup for distinct values. I'm not sure what it is exactly you're trying to do - do you want distinct values from a selection of 10, or a selection of ten values from a distinct result set?

Comment: If you put an index on `group_id` and `category`, MySQL can simply find the correct `category` entry and spit out everything it has on the `group_id` side, subject to the LIMIT clause. It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with your code at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will find the first 200 distinct rows, then output the next 10. The `DISTINCT` is done before the `LIMIT`. Depending on indexing and how the table is stored, it can stop collecting unique values once it fulfills the limit clause. This is most likely if the value you want distinct is indexed.

(BTW, you will improve readability of the query if you use `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 200` instead of the older unintuitive `LIMIT 200, 10` notation.)